# Why does my discord bot return a nicely sorted list as intended on my local system, but completely chaotic lists when deployed on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I have a discord bot that has a command that gives back a bunch of files, i want to send them alphabetically so its more clear to read.

```
@commands.command(help="Display mp3 files")
async def mp3s(self, ctx):
    files = os.listdir('res/mp3s/')
    audiofiles = []
    for x in files:
        if ('.mp3' or '.wav') in str(x):
            audiofiles.append(x)
    print(len(str(audiofiles)))
    if len(str(audiofiles)) > 2000:
        print("MP3stats requested by {}".format(ctx.author))
        templist = []
        for x in audiofiles:
            templist.append(x)
            if len(templist) % 25 == 0:
                print("test")
                await ctx.send(templist)
                templist = []
        await ctx.send(templist)
```

When i test this on my local system, it gives back a nicely sorted list.

[image]

However, when i run it on heroku, it gives a completely chaotic list back, and i dont understand why and what i can do against it.

It sends this in discord:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you could simply sort the list

```py
>>> lst = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e']
>>> lst.sort()
>>> print(lst)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> 
>>> # Or
>>> lst = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e']
>>> lst = sorted(lst)
>>> print(lst)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: im not sure you understood the question - there is no need to sort the list, it is already sorted and working fine, the question is why this is not the case when the script is running on heroku.

Comment: I'm not sure, but - `and i dont understand why and what i can do against it.` - you can sort it! It gives you the result you want

Comment: You should never rely on the OS to do your sorting anyway. This is a very reasonable solution. And based on some Googling, this is normal for Heroku